# Loading index.php contents which located outside blog folder for post single page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm creating **blog** page as WordPress for my static PHP website. When blog page URL changes to `pretty permalink` (`example.com/blog/my-post-page`), loading contents (not redirecting to index.php, only contents loading and URL will be like http://example.com/blog/my-post-page) of `index.php` (home page for my site) that is located outside blog folder instead of `single.php` contents.

When **permalink** changes to `default` (`example.com/blog/?p=123`), it will work perfectly.

I need URL as http://example.com/blog/my-post-page.

EDIT : - I have updated permalink to Custom Structure as `/index.php/%postname%/`. But now post pages are showing with `example.com/blog/index.php/my-post-page`.

I think the issue raised with the new WordPress version. (Version 4.2.2).
Any solutions to remove `index.php` from URL ?

My Directory Structure:-

```
/                                          - Root
/blog                                      - Blog folder
/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/           - Theme folder
/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/single.php - Post Single page

/index.php                                 - Home page (Loading contents of this file)
```

My htaccess :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I delete/rename index.php in root folder, page will show not found error.

Comment: I don't get the part where you're talking about `index.php` (the root one, outside of `blog` directory) and `single.php` (what is it ? What does this file have to do here ?)

Comment: @JustinIurman my post page is index.php and post detail page is single.php (WP concept). Here the problem is , in outside blog folder there is another file named as index.php (Home page for site). When I access post detail page in blog as pretty permalink (example.com/blog/my-post-page) it will redirected to index.php file outside my blog folder. Then I changed permalink to Custom Structure as /index.php/%postname%/. Then post detail page is loading correct but link contains index.php ( example.com/blog/index.php/my-post-page).

Comment: Well, just to be sure... Your WP directory is `blog` right ? Could you update your question with your current WP htaccess ? Because it's weird it's rewriting to root index instead of blog folder index... Unless you have an issue in htaccess paths for instance

Comment: @Sree is your WP installed in Blog? if so what is the index.php for in the root directory? Please provide this info?

Comment: @JustinIurman yes. WP directory is blog. I have updated my htaccess file. But my site will work without htaccess file.

Comment: @PanamaJack yes. WP installed in Blog. But here my problem is loading index.php(home page for my site , outside of blog folder) contents when access my post single page.

Comment: @Sree If I understand your question correctly, you try to give Wordpress a different url than where it is installed. In that case see [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Answer (score 4):

in `htaccess` you can write any regex expression for url rewrite 
in your case

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/\(.+)$ /blog/index.php?postname=$1
```

this line means that if url starts with `/blog/` anything after `/` would be passed to `/blog/index.php` as `postname` parameter. 
`example.com/blog/my-post-page` would be rewritten as `example.com/blog/index.php?postname=my-post-page`

you can exclude anything from this rule

for example let's exclude this: `/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/` 
it would go like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+))/blog/\(.+)$ /blog/index.php?postname=$1
```

Comment: could you please update answer with full htaccess code?

Comment: I didn't fully understood all rewrite rules you would like to apply. Can you comment full map? in `example.com/blog/my-post-page ` ->  `example.com/blog/index.php?postname=my-post-page` this type of format?

Answer (score 2):

It should work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: quite similar case to your, have a look

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pretty-permalinks-redirects-to-indexphp

Comment: Yes. From the above link I have updated permalink to custom as /index.php/%postname%/. But now post pages are showing with example.com/blog/index.php/my-post-page. How to remove it?

Comment: in Permalinks in wp-admin (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php): 
i selected Custom and this in the custom field 

/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

In your case it would be just
" /%postname%/ "

If it's already set like that change it to the default setting, save the changes and change it back to this setting and re-apply the change just in case.
 that .htaccess should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes here, change `permalink` to `/%postname%/`.

and change .htaccess to following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```